# Providing "translations" based on region rather than language

Tags: forms, i18n-l10n

We are using FAPI to create some custom forms (actually extending the registration form) and want to provide different form labels based on a Country of Residence. For example if in Australia they will be asked to enter "City/Town/Suburb" but if they're in New Zealand the label will be "City".

Is this something that can be done and managed with Drupal's base translation modules? My understanding so far is that most of this functionality is at the language level rather than "regional" settings. If not, what would be a plan for managing this in a maintainable way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [addressfield](http://drupal.org/project/addressfield) module does this.  You can check their code to see how you can implement such a feature in D7.

Comment: addressfield basically provides it's own overrides based on arrays of country codes. It seems the answer is that it can't be done using normal translation functions.